# Unable to submit drupal menu add form using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drupal

I am trying to create a new menu in drupal (8 URL: `<site url>/admin/structure/menu/add`) using the python selenium chrome webdriver. But every time I try to submit the form, nothing happens.

I have tried every form of form submission I could think of:

I have tried targeting the div of the submit button and hover+clicking

```py
save_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-actions']")
Hover = ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(pages_menu)
Hover.click().perform()
```

I have tried just clicking the input

```py
save_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-submit']")
save_button.click()
```

I tried using the .submit() function on every field

```py
menu_title_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-label']")
administrative_summary_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-description']")

menu_title_input.submit()
administrative_summary_input.submit()
```

I even tried sending keys to the input

```py
save_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-submit']")
save_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I would expect that any of these should submit the form and add the menu, but the page seems to be ignoring it completely. It also jumps up to the top of the page when the button is clicked, if that information is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after ages of digging it turns out that to generate a machine name in drupal the javascript needs you to fake a click and enter characters that way so it can generate the machine name on input. Here is the code I got to work:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

menu_title_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-label']")
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menu_title_input).click(menu_title_input).send_keys(Keys.END + Keys.SPACE + Keys.BACKSPACE + Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: Does less than 2 hours qualify as "ages"?

Comment: 2 hours is NOTHING when dealing with selenium/chromedriver! .click() should have worked here! :D

Comment: I posted the question after already trying for several hours. Don't know how long in total... don't want to know :(

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and check how many elements do you had:

```
len(browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-submit']"))
```

if it goes up maybe it's going for different element. If wolud be more than 1, you just need to find right X:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='edit-submit']")[X].your_operations
```

Comment: Turns out drupal apparently needs you to fake a typing input in the box. Just filling out the form field dosen't do it. The machine name for the menu won't be generated otherwise.